# Unity3d crashes android plugin

Tags: plugins, android-studio, unity-game-engine, crash

I tried creating an android plugin for unity3d in android studio, following exactly some tutorials online. But everytime I modified the manifest the game would crash.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to help you if you don't provide any information about the specific tutorial you're following, the specific modifications you're doing and the specific stacktrace for the crash of your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had many issues with the Manifest as well.  One thing I found that might be helpful is, every time you install another plugin check the plugin in directory for another manifest file.  It seems unity at build time will take all these manifests and create one manifest from them...which is nice.  But when the manifest is causing a crash, it makes it very hard to debug.

What you can try is to rename all the manifests to something else and manually create a manifest file from all the plugin manifests...this way you can rearrange the order of the items in the manifest and see if this corrects the problem.  I know sometimes simply rearranging items can fix a crash.

Give it a shot.

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:-

```
// If your module is a library project, this is needed
//to properly recognize 'android-library' plugin
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion = 17

sourceSets {
    main  {
        // Here is the path to your source code
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
}

// This is the actual solution, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19037807/1002054
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
delete 'build/libs/myCompiledLibrary.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
from('build/bundles/release/')
into('build/libs/')
include('classes.jar')
rename ('classes.jar', 'myCompiledLibrary.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```