# Generate two source Jars for different folders in Gradle?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I use the Gradle Java plugin and have the following source structure:

```
src/main/java/package1/
src/main/java/package2/
```

I want to create two source jars for each package directory, i.e.,

```
myproject-package1-sources-1.0.jar
myproject-package2-sources-1.0.jar
```

I can create the source jar for the whole project with:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) { 
  classifier = 'sources' 
  from sourceSets.main.allSource 
}

artifacts { 
   archives sourcesJar 
}
```

How can I create source jar for two projects with the appropriate names?

Edit: It could be that package1 and package2 are somewhere deeper like

```
src/main/java/a/b/e/package1/ 
src/main/java/x/y/z/package2/
```

It could also be possible that there are multiple packages1 and 2 like:

```
src/main/java/a/b/e/package1/ 
src/main/java/qwer/package1/ 
src/main/java/x/y/z/package2/
```

I want that that all files and subsequent files which are in folders named `packages1` are includes it the first source jar and the same for the other package.

Comment: You want two instead of all together? The best way would be to have your project in a separate module.

Comment: I cannot split the project.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: No I have not solved the issue.

Comment: What did my answer not solve for you?

Comment: What is the status of this?

Comment: What happened to your reputation? You got banned for a while. I answered your question. I can not see why.

Comment: There are more than one user from the same ip.

Answer (score 0):

### This question is very similar to the one I just answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29946192/950427.

Since you have "two" project that are in the "same" module or you have no modules what so ever, you need to be manually "specify" which directories you want.

### You will need something like this:

```
task project1(type: Copy) {
    from('build/classes/main/package1/')

    into('another directory/')
    include('classes.jar')
}

task project2(type: Copy) {
    from('build/classes/main/package2/')

    into('another directory/')
    include('classes.jar')
}
```

Comment: I need a more general approach. I need to include all files in folders containing the pattern **package1**

Comment: So you didn't try my answer?

Comment: @This is not want I want exaclty!

Comment: @confile I am asking for more information. `from('build/classes/main/package1/')` get's all the directories below it. What else do you want?