# How to compile JAR for the SuperSLiM library?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, superslim

I'm an android newbie, and would like to create a jar file for this library:

https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM

I've read some other online answers which say that the gradle build file has to be modified, which I tried to do, but not sure if I did it correctly:

[How to create an Android Library Jar with gradle without publicly revealing source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034466/how-to-create-a-jar-with-gradle-without-publicly-revealing-source-code/19037807#19037807)

Can anyone help me with this??

My goal is to use the *.jar file to create an Android Binding Project within a Xamarin project to be able to use the library in Xamarin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created the necessary bindings, you can check out the (pretty simple) binding project on https://github.com/dmunch/SuperSLiM-binding or download the NuGet at https://www.nuget.org/packages/SuperSLiM/

Comment: Quick question, did you achieve this by applying the steps mentioned below in Tonic's reply??  Thanks!

Comment: I basically followed the steps of the [Xamarin documentation for creating java bindings](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/). The only thing not straightforward was finding the right entries for the [Metadata.xml](https://github.com/dmunch/SuperSLiM-binding/blob/master/Transforms/Metadata.xml) source code transformations.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Xamarin user myself, but a quick look at the [Xamarin changelog](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_4/xamarin.android_4.7/#Xamarin.Android_4.7.10) indicates that you can use the **Build Action** of *LibraryProjectZip* to bind a .aar project, which is what SuperSLiM is.

To actually make sense of this, here is a [blog post](http://codemilltech.com/climbing-gumdrop-mountain-or-how-to-create-xamarin-android-bindings/) which may also be useful. From the article it seems you need to download the .aar file from one of the hosted locations, [bintray](https://bintray.com/tonicartos/maven/com.tonicartos%3Asuperslim/0.4.13/view#files) or [mavencentral](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.tonicartos%7Csuperslim%7C0.4.13%7C), and follow some instructions to create the Xamarin binding.