# How can I use Gradle to build a jar with required libraries in a sub-folder (like Eclipse) for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-gradle-plugin

In Eclipse, you can create a project jar with its required dependencies in an adjacent sub-folder by doing ...

- Export->Java->Runnable JAR file
- Select Library handling option: Copy required libraries into a    sub-folder next to the generated JAR

**Is there a way to do this with the Gradle?**

PS: I am working on gradle 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Gradle task for copying, like so:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from('path/to/dir/with/lib/jars/')
    into('path/to/subfolder/next/to/generated/jar/')
    include('names.jar','of.jar','jars.jar','to.jar','copy.jar')
}

copyLibs.dependsOn(build)
```

**Edit:**

```
task combinedJar(type: Jar) {
   from zipTree("path/to/generated.jar")
   from "path/to/subfolder/next/to/generated/jar/"
}

combinedJar.dependsOn(copyLibs)
```

Run via `gradlew copyLibs`. You can make the task depend on the build task that builds your project.

Note that you may have to also create the `path/to/subfolder/next/to/generated/jar/` in the task.

Comment: I don't think it works. I mean I need merge the external jar into the released jar, but not copy the 3rd jar to someplace.

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood the original question. I've made an edit. See if that, or a modification of that, works for you.

Comment: path/to/subfolder/next/to/generated/jar/ is path of external jar and path/to/generated.jar is the released jar which I mentioned, right ?

Comment: I am sorry, I will not be able to provide exact code without more description, a screenshot of your folder tree, etc. Check out the Gradle guide here and see if you can put together what you need: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide