# Application works if library is connected to source, but not from jar created from that source

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android library and want to distribute it like jar.

I create the demo project that shows how my library works and add gradle dependency from my library:

```
compile project(':my-library')
```

Then I build the project, it works fine. Than I take `jar` file from my library (from build/intermediates/bundles/release - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19037807/1159507)), and put it to `libs` directory and replace the dependency with this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

But I was very surprised because the demo app did not work. I tried to clean, make `jar` more times, clear cache, test it on different Android versions from 4.0 till 6.0.1 but the same picture: it works if library is connected to sources, but does not work if library is connected like jar created from that sources.

My library is quite big, and I'm not sure what exactly goes wrong. In normal conditions it should load some javascript from server, run it and show some results in WebView, but in case of jar file I see only empty screen.

How is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? And the problem is only at runtime? You can compile and use the library in your code just fine?

Comment: @XaverKapeller I'm debugging now, but I believe it will takes few days. Yes, the problem in runtime. Not got you last question.

Comment: Do you have also the resources in your android library?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti no, just java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue:

In my library I have dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

And don't have it on my demo project.

And it hungs on this lines, inside library:

```
    Info adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(mContext);
```

The solution is to add dependency on demo also, use some other method to get Google Advertising id.