# Copying Android Studio Project to Eclipse Project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am copying Android Studio Project to Eclipse for testing it in Eclipse. I copied the java folder into src of Eclipse and also modified the res and Manifest file as per Android Studio Project. The only problem now is jar files. I dont know where it is located in Android Studio Project and also how to use these jars in Eclipse directly from Android Studio Project.

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763090/how-to-export-library-to-jar-in-android-studio#answer-17132055) Maybe is a solution for your problem

Comment: Actually my requirement is i need to use jar of Android Studio project in Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder named "lib" at your project folder. Then put all your jars into it. And create new dummy android project, cross check the folders.