# Gradle (Android Studio) does not generate jar file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, jar

I'm working on an android plugin for unity and need to generate a jar file.
To do so I followed the steps at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20446513/3742608 , set my build variant to release, rebuild the project and executed makeJar.
However, my project does have the folder gradle uses only in another folder 'intermediates':

[image: Project Structure]

I changed some things to the following, but it doesn't matter, the jar file is not generated.

```
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/libs/myCompiledLibrary.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('build/libs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'myCompiledLibrary.jar')
}
```

The bundles/release directory is empty, as are its underlying directories. The code also doesn't work if I reference classes/release instead of bundles/release.

Anyone an idea why the jar file is not generated?

P.S. the classes.jar in the directory libs is not generated by gradle, but just the classes.jar provided by Unity

Comment: I have the same promble, I think it's cause by instant run, but I also have no idea to slove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I used Android Studio, I was told that it is not possible to generate **jar** file from Android Studio. I don't know if this has changed since then.

Now to answer your question, you don't need **jar** file to make your plugin work in Unity. Unity 5.0 added support for **aar** file. Simply compile your plugin as **arr** file and use it in your Unity 5 or above version and it should work.