# Android Studio Export jar not exporting any jar

Tags: android, gradle, jar, export

I am fairly new to android studio, and I am trying to export a jar out of an Android Studio project for another Unity project.

I followed the instruction given on the link [Create An Android Plugin For Unity Using Android Studio](http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/android-plugin-unity-android-studio.html)

But whenever I'm trying to export its showing "Build Successful" and "External task execution finished 'exportJar'" but I am not able to find any jar in specified folder of gradle file.

I looked into the folders "app/release"  its empty and "app/build/intermediates/bundles/release/"  contains only another folder named "instant-run".

So I am bit confused whether I am skipping any step or looking on the wrong path.

I m using Android Studio v2.1.2

App.build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.merchantapp"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile files('libs/PGSDK_v1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/classes.jar')
}
task deleteOldJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'release/AndroidPlugin.jar'
}

//task to export contents as jar
task exportJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    ///Rename the jar
    rename('classes.jar', 'AndroidPlugin.jar')
}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)


android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }
}
```

Comment: have you seen this path build/intermediates/bundles/release/ ?

Comment: Yes. Its empty and contains another folder instant-run

Comment: can you see .aar file under build/output/aar? @Pranav Buradkar

Comment: No. the "build" folder contains a folder named "outputs"  and "apk" within the "outputs" but no ".aar"

Comment: you should change this line apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 to apply plugin: 'com.android.library' it is mandatory. and then rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks @JaydeepPatel it worked. I missed some changes that author has mentioned in second part of the tutorial.

Comment: great always welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change this line

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

to

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

it is mandatory. and then rebuild your project.
cause we are generating library and it should required for build jar file.
reference [How to export library to Jar in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763090/how-to-export-library-to-jar-in-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks @Pranav Burakar

Comment: In my case it's still not exporting any jar