# Create library of my android project to use another project using android studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I want  to create a library of my own project which include java source code, resources (manifest, layout) file and I'm using **Android Studio 2.1.2**. Please give me any suggestions how I can create that one and also following one -
1) Want to create .jar library not `.AAR`.
2) How to add another library or any dependencies in to it, is it possible??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you searched samething on SO before posting question ?

Comment: yes, i got only how to create .aar file.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change in your app's build.gradle file

search line

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

and change it to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

and most important thing remove line

```
applicationId "your_package_name"
```

from the defaultConfig block. because libraries do not have application Id. and then build your project you'll find 'aar' folder inside you build folder.

> projectfolder -> build -> output -> aar -> library_file

**Edited :**

and for Jar file please go through with the below command

> [Run gradlew makeJar command from your project root.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20446513/1160282)

Comment: ok. but how i customise that .aar file meas if i want to show resources folder to user is it possible??

Comment: i want to create user friendly library, by using it user can edit UI of library but cant see source code.

Answer (score 0):

see these tutorials... 
[How to make a .jar out from an Android Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project)

http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/export-jar-file-from-android-studio-project/

Comment: 1) **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project** will create only source code how can i add my resources??

Comment: 2) **http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/export-jar-file-from-android-studio-project/** will create jar but after adding this .jar file in to another project it gives error of missing configuration files

Comment: error - **android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {'pakage name of another app'.tabexample/'pakage name of library'.NextActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle file

```
build.gradle file  apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
         main {
             //Path to your source code
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/../lib'
            }
        }
    }

    // This is important, it will run lint checks but won't abort build
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/AdvancedWebView.jar')
    compile project(':ShortcutBadger')
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}

task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'release/' + POM_ARTIFACT_ID + '_' + VERSION_NAME + '.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/debug/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', POM_ARTIFACT_ID + '_' +  VERSION_NAME + '.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

and this is my mainifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package name">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"                
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".NextActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```