# Gradle and multiple projects with Roboguice dependency

Tags: android, gradle, roboguice

I'm trying to migrate an old IntelliJ project to use gradle. However, assembleDebug fails during the dx step:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/inject/AbstractModule;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

My project is split into two subprojects: a main project and a library project. Both these project have Roboguice and Guice as dependencies.

I tried Xav's suggested workaround for including the support library in multiple projects as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16746682/346975). The workaround should probably not even be necessary, given that roboguice/guice are both picked up from maven central. I created a dummy library project that's the only project that depends on roboguice/guice. I made it so that my main project and the (true) library project both depend on this dummy project. However, I get the same error.

How can this be fixed?

**settings.gradle** in the root directory:

```
include 'MainApp'
include 'library'
include 'common-library'
```

**build.gradle** in the root directory:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
  }
}

allprojects {
    version = '1.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-reporting'
```

**build.gradle** in the main project and the real library project:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "17.0"
    sourceSets         {
      main {
           manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
           java.srcDirs = ['src']
           res.srcDirs = ['res']
      }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library') // only in main, not in real library
    compile project(':common-library')
}
```

**build.gradle** in the dummy library project:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "17.0"
    sourceSets         {
      main {
           manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
           java.srcDirs = ['src']
           res.srcDirs = ['res']
      }
    }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
  compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right that the dummy library isn't necessary since you're using Maven. If you look at the [.pom for Roboguice](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/roboguice/roboguice/2.0/roboguice-2.0.pom), it lists Guice as a dependency with the "no_aop" classifier. However, you're also listing Guice explicitly without the classifier. My guess is that Maven is pulling in both versions, which results in the dexing merge conflict.

Try removing `compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'` from your Gradle build file and see if it builds.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Don't quite remember why I felt I needed to add guice to dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys I founded!
To solve this issue you have use '**exclude module**' on build.gradle for library-project.

Here is my examples:
    compile ('oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'httpcore' }